# Is there a CSS Selector to select divs which have a number as id

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, css-selectors

I want to select some divs within a HTML page which have an id attribute containing a number. I can't come up with a CSS Selector. Should i go through all the divs and test their id attributes or there is a magic CSS selector for this.

```html
...
<div id="56142307907">...</div>
...
<div id="58308926711">...</div>
...
```

#### Note

A JS only solution is preferred

Comment: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/css-selector-for-element-which-have-numbers-as-class-name-b6a089989199

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If you look at [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/) you will see the closest thing to that are the various attribute selectors, but they only match on exact strings or substrings.

Since you mention JS, the easiest approach would probably be to get all the divs with an id, then filter them.

```js
const regex = /^\d+$/;
const filter = element => regex.test(element.id);
const divs_with_ids = document.querySelectorAll("div[id]");
const divs_with_numeric_ids = Array.from(divs_with_ids).filter(filter);
console.log(divs_with_numeric_ids);
```

```html
<div></div>
<div id="134"></div>
<p id="234"></div>
<div id="13d4"></div>
<div id="54354"></div>
<div id="5643f"></div>
<div id="454354"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## You can do it in pure CSS...

...if you are *very* determined.

---

## Available characters

[HTML4 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) says:

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[HTML5](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-id-attribute) widens the pool of available characters:

> the **id** attribute value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's tree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any ASCII whitespace.

---

## Solution

I'll proceed with the assumption that you're only using letters, digits, and `-_:.` as IDs in your DOM. If you need a tighter selector, just add more elements to it.

So... here's the monster selector that fits the above criteria:

```css
div[id^='0']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='1']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='2']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='3']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='4']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='5']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='6']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='7']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='8']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='9']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.'])
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  width: 20rem;
  background-color: #ddf;
}

div[id^='0']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='1']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='2']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='3']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='4']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='5']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='6']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='7']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='8']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']),
div[id^='9']:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*=':']):not([id*='.']) {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">id: 1</div>
<div id="23">id: 23</div>
<div id="345">id: 345</div>
<div id="4567">id: 4567</div>
<div id="56789">id: 56789</div>
<div id="12345-6789">id: 12345-6789</div>
<div id="0123-some-text-here-4567">id: 0123-some-text-here-4567</div>
<div id="000-starts-with-digits">id: 000-starts-with-digits</div>
<div id="ends-with-digits-321">id: ends-with-digits-321</div>
<div id="only-text">id: only-text</div>
<div>(id is not provided)</div>
<div id>(id has no value)</div>
<div id="">(id is an empty string)</div>
```

---

## Explanation

CSS allows for selecting elements by their attributes' values. [The syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) includes a `[attr*=value]` selector, which can be used for checking for substrings.

By chaining that selector, surrounded with `:not()`, one can filter out all unwanted values.

Note that each of the combined selectors starts with `[id^='digit']`, from 0 to 9. Without this, it could match elements which have empty id. By specifying that the string starts with a digit, proper elements are filtered out.

---

## Slightly simpler approach

You could go with a ten times shorter selector, but it will select elements with empty id, i.e. `<div id></div>` and `<div id=""></div>`. If you don't mind the downsides, you can use this:

```css
div[id]:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*='.']):not([id*=':'])
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem;
  border: 3px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 12pt;
  width: 20rem;
  background-color: #ddf;
}

div[id]:not([id*='A' i]):not([id*='B' i]):not([id*='C' i]):not([id*='D' i]):not([id*='E' i]):not([id*='F' i]):not([id*='G' i]):not([id*='H' i]):not([id*='I' i]):not([id*='J' i]):not([id*='K' i]):not([id*='L' i]):not([id*='M' i]):not([id*='N' i]):not([id*='O' i]):not([id*='P' i]):not([id*='Q' i]):not([id*='R' i]):not([id*='S' i]):not([id*='T' i]):not([id*='U' i]):not([id*='V' i]):not([id*='W' i]):not([id*='X' i]):not([id*='Y' i]):not([id*='Z' i]):not([id*='-']):not([id*='_']):not([id*='.']):not([id*=':']) {
  border-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="1">id: 1</div>
<div id="23">id: 23</div>
<div id="345">id: 345</div>
<div id="4567">id: 4567</div>
<div id="56789">id: 56789</div>
<div id="12345-6789">id: 12345-6789</div>
<div id="0123-some-text-here-4567">id: 0123-some-text-here-4567</div>
<div id="000-starts-with-digits">id: 000-starts-with-digits</div>
<div id="ends-with-digits-321">id: ends-with-digits-321</div>
<div id="only-text">id: only-text</div>
<div>(id is not provided)</div>
<div id>(id has no value)</div>
<div id="">(id is an empty string)</div>
```

Answer (score -5):

There is no such selector that can play with ids having numerical values.
However, data-id can be of your use.

For example, your div looks like below-

```
<div id="12345"></div>
```

Add a data-d attribute to it, to make it look like-

```
<div id="12345" data-id="12345"></div>
```

And then a querySelector on data attribute can serve the purpose.

```
document.querySelector('[data-id="12345"')
```

Note- You may skip the id part all together, if that is not required.

Comment: `data-id` will have exactly the same problems as `id` … and `[data-id="12345"` (a) has a syntax error and (b) will make an exact match for **that** number instead of matching **any** number.